# SQL Query: Inner Joins

Tags: mysql, database, join

**I am working on a sql query to do the following:**

Make a list of all project numbers for projects that involve an employee whose last name is 'Smith', either as a worker or as a manager of the department that controls the project.

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
SELECT 
     project.PNO
FROM department 
     INNER JOIN project ON department.DNO=project.DNO
     INNER JOIN works_on ON project.PNO = works_on.PNO
     INNER JOIN employee ON employee.SSN = works_on.ESSN
WHERE employee.LNAME LIKE 'Smith'
```

**It returns:**

PNO

1

2

**My problem is that I can not figure out how to check if their is a manager named smith for the project with out joining the department table in somewhere**

**Attached is my schema**

[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHQO0.png)

Comment: Why you don't have workers and managers in the same table `Employee`? I think it could be easier for doing what you're looking for.

Comment: @Carlos Parra  Can you explain this further? I have a table of employees where some employees are managers of others, as well as a works_on table which shows how many hours each employee spend on particular projects

Comment: Yes, I saw the ER Diagram. But, what I mean is since workers and managers are almost the same (with the difference if it's manager or not) you could create a one-to-many relationship with the same table `Employee` to set what employee is going to be the manager of others employees. I don't know if you're following me. Then, you could just add a column to be related with your `Employee` pk, as fk.

Comment: Finally, you should include this `fk` column in the `SELECT projects.PMO, employee.fk` to see the manager of each project, of course if there exists a manager whose last name `LNAME` is 'Smith'. Hope it could help.